# Error al transferir dominio de GoDaddy a Siteground

Tags: dns

Cometí un error al transferir mi dominio de GoDaddy a SiteGround para crear un nuevo WordPresss desde 0 allí. El asunto fue que transferí el dominio sin cambiar previamente los DNS en GoDaddy por los de SiteGround y al Instalar el nuevo WordPress no puedo ver la página ahora! Como se borró la instalación de WordPress en GoDaddy, y se transfirió el dominio no puedo ver los DNS que tenía allí!
Mi pregunta sería: Si tengo los DNS que tenía en GoDaddy copiados en un archivo de texto y los remplazo en mi SiteGround podré tener acceso de nuevo a mi WordPress con el mismo dominio?

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En en panel donde tienes el nuevo dominio busca algo como: "Servidores de nombres" o DNS y cambialos por los de tu hosting y eso será todo.

[image: Panel DNS godaddy]

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! Cambiaría los que tenía antes en GoDaddy Y ponerlos en SiteGound. Al cerrar la cuenta de GoDaddy no se perdería la información?

Comment: hiciste un respaldo ¿verdad?

Comment: Tengo en un archivo de texto de las anteriores DNS, las que tenía en GoDaddy

Comment: ¿migraste completo el wordpress o es una instalación nueva? cuando migras de proveedores por lo regular siempre te especifican que respaldes antes; es casi seguro que la información que tenías antes se pierda si no tienes respaldo.

Comment: No, es una instalación nueva! Por lo mismo no creí que fuera necesario cambiar los DNS al empezar desde 0 en otro hosting. Pero al querer acceder con el mismo dominio no es posible hacerlo. Es evidente que soy absolutamente novato en esto jajaja! Estuve revisando en muchos sitios y la documentación de ambos proveedores pero no conseguí respuesta a ello!

Comment: ¿dónde estás hosteando?

Comment: En SiteGround... Quise cambiar de GoDaddy a SiteGround por la posiblidad de usar en este Let's Encrypt y la creación de los mail con el dominio ya en el plan incluidos! El WordPress que tenía en GoDaddy no tenía nada pues no había arrancado el proyecto aún, por eso lo borré y decidí comenzar de nuevo en este.

Comment: ¿ya tomaste en cuenta que en ocasiones tarda en replicarse el cambio de DNS?

Comment: Sé que se tarda apróximadamente entre una semana y 14 días la transferencia de dominio y unas 48 horas la actualización de los DNS... Pero al verificar el estado de la transferencia del dominio, ya aparece con status "Active" dentro del apartado de dominios de mi cuenta de SiteGround. Debería esperar un poco más para poder acceder a mi WordPress? La transferencia se realizó hace una semana aprox.

Comment: ¿ya hiciste un whois? para saber a qué ip o DNS está apuntando el dominio

Comment: Mmm... eso no lo he hecho. No conocía esa opción! Ya mismo me pongo en eso!

Comment: Inténtalo y salimos de dudas

Comment: Efectivamente, aún apunta a los DNS que tenía en la cuenta de GoDaddy

Comment: por eso no resuelve, saludos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Juan! Entonces reemplazarlos en SiteGround por los anteriores y listo?

Comment: reemplaza los DNS en siteground. Saludos